# how to enter variables from a url in a php array

Tags: php, arrays, variables

a newbie question!

I have set up some code to create an image with this url:

> www.mywebpage.php?wc1=99&wc2=6&wc3=23

In a php page want to use the wc1, wc2 and wc3 variables from the url as inputs to a bar chart graphic

the code on the receiving webpage includes this line:

```
$datay=array($_REQUEST['wc1'], $_REQUEST['wc2'], $_REQUEST['wc3']);
```

and using the datay array I get a nice bar chart with three bars.

My problem is I want to create urls with any number of wc? variables, and then create an array with any number of bars in the resulting bar chart.  The numbero f bars should be dynamically set by some other real-time process.

So I realise I need to embed this line of code:

```
$datay=array($_REQUEST['wc1'], $_REQUEST['wc2'], $_REQUEST['wc3']);
```

in a loop and add in variablles to the array one by one until they are all added (whatever number there are).

However, I am stuck at the first hurdle as I do not know how to add a variable to the array.

This code does not work:

```
$firstBit = $_REQUEST['wc1'];
$datay=array(firstBit, $_REQUEST['wc2'], $_REQUEST['wc3']);
```

Answer (score 1):

You're just missing the `$` from your variable name

```
 $datay=array($firstBit, $_REQUEST['wc2'], $_REQUEST['wc3']);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($_GET as $key=>$value){
    echo $key;
    echo "<br/>";
    echo $value;
    echo "<br/>";
}
```

You'll soon understand

Answer (score 0):

In your request, pass the values thus:

```
www.mywebpage.php?wc[]=99&wc[]=6&wc[]=23
```

And then you have an array out of the box...

```
$myArray = $_REQUEST['wc'];
```

Comment: @Dean it also means you don't need to change the code when you add the forth and fifth value and so on.